# Jabber client with old SSL support

Tags: xmpp

The company I'm working for is using a Jabber server which is kind of old. It doesn't support SSL/TLS with SASL but only plain old SSL.

I tried a dozen of Jabber clients for Android but none of them supports this setup.

Are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 2):

[Jabiru](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.mzet.jabiru) project has "legacy SSL" option.

Answer (score 0):

IM+ also has the option for "Use old-style SSL" - it appears to be more than just the port 5223, as disabling the option and setting the port manually, doesn't allow authentication.